# How to label a few selective samples in PCA plot

Tags: r

[image: plot]

I have created a PCA plot using `prcomp` in R using:

```
> input <- read_excel("input.xlsx")                                                          
> data<-input[,!names(input) %in% "gene"]
> data1<-t(as.matrix(data[-1])) %*% as.matrix(data[-1]) / ncol(data)
> res.pca <- prcomp(data1, scale = TRUE)
> par(cex=0.5)
> plot(res.pca$x[,1],res.pca$x[,2], xlab="PC1", ylab = "PC2", main = "PC1 / PC2 - plot")
```

The `input.xlsx` file looks like:

```
gene    Sample1 Sample2     Sample3
A   13.932431   5.366284    6.93992
B   21.111017   0.662061    1.563687
C   26.471751   0.932416    1.673144
D   27.597507   36.591138   28.371248
E   35.324703   0           1.462438
```

I want to add labels to a few samples only. I was able to add labels to all the samples using:

```
text(res.pca$x[,1], res.pca$x[,2], rownames(input), pos= 1 )
```

But I have a lot of samples and the PCA point labels are not clear so I want to label only a few points. I want to do this to compare this PCA plot with another PCA plot os same samples using different approaches.

Comment: If you want to keep labels from overlapping, maybe take a look at the answers to this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16057/how-do-i-avoid-overlapping-labels-in-an-r-plot

Comment: I have a few hundred samples and their names are long. It is not possible for them to not overlap. Is there a way to just label a few. Like I want to label left side points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To label just a few points on the left side try:

```
Threshold = -30
LEFT = which(res.pca$x[,1] + res.pca$x[,2] < Threshold)
text(res.pca$x[LEFT,1], res.pca$x[LEFT,2], rownames(input)[LEFT], pos= 1 )
```

Try a few different values of `Threshold` to change how many points are labeled.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Can it be done to the lower points based on y-axis?

Comment: Yes,  you just need a way to specify the points that you want.  Maybe something like `BOTTOM = which(res.pca$x[,2] < -30); 
text(res.pca$x[BOTTOM ,1], res.pca$x[BOTTOM ,2], rownames(input)[BOTTOM ], pos= 1 )`

Comment: It worked, thank you! I wanted to modify the labels as some of them are still overlapping. I want to make them smaller and portion them a little bit farther. I tried using pos and cex but it is not changing anything.

Comment: Is there a way to color code a few samples by names based on input file?

Comment: Yes. Do you want to color the points or the labels?

Comment: I want to add color to some of the data points. For example, based on the input file, there is one samples "A" and I want to color that data point in the plot.

Comment: What plot statement did you use?

Comment: BOTTOM = which(res.pca$x[,2] < -30);  
text(res.pca$x[BOTTOM ,1], res.pca$x[BOTTOM ,2], colnames(input)[BOTTOM ], pos= 1).

Comment: I do not see a plot in there. I mean how did you initially plot the points?

Comment: I have edited the original post with how I got the plot and how the input data looks.